# To find the frequency of whole audio stream in java using FFT?

Tags: java, audio

Basically I tried a lot to find frequency of audio recorded in `.wav` format in java. I understood from previous questions that I need to apply FFT on recorded audio. I searched a lot but i couldn't understand about how to apply FFT. I want help for my these two problems....

1.From java documentation i read that...PCM encoding accepts the audio data on time domain basis. It stores the pressure point of audio depending on sample Rate in an array.(ex. if sampleRate is 44100 , then during encoding AudioFormat method in java will check for 44100 subsequent pressure points for each second ). But for applying FFT we will need to get this time domain info of audio.I tried following code to just print that array...but i am not sure that this is that actual time domain info or not..pz help me for this

```
  targetLine.start();

  data = new byte[targetLine.getBufferSize() /5];
  .
  .
  .     
for(int j=0;j<data.length;j++)
  {
       System.out.print(data[j]+","); 
  }
```

('data' is that array)

output looks like :

```
95,45,-49,51,-127,57,-51,62,119,67,-82,71,98,75,79,78,-54,80,-87,82,-15,83,-6,84,123,85,-104,85,121,85,...
```

till data.length reached.

AND

2.How to apply FFT on this time domain info....i checked many tutorials...many algorithms but i couldn't understand that. plz suggest me any site or tutorial to learn how to apply FFT.

Comment: An audio stream *doesn't have* a single frequency - unless you know it's a pure sine wave, or similar?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the Processing language? If not, it shouldn't be tagged with [tag:processing].

Comment: @immibis   .....    Actually I want to check for frequency change. Suppose we process audio of a song ..then different notes will have different frequencies. I want to check this change in frequency and want to calculate the actual change in frequency.